# Subclassing a Typhoon assembly to override methods not working

Tags: ios, swift, typhoon

I am subclassing a Typhoon assembly such that stubbed implementations are returned, for unit testing purposes.

My assembly looks something like this:

```
class RealAssembly : TyphoonAssembly {
  public dynamic func instanceToStubOut() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(SomeRealWorldClass.self)
  }

  public dynamic func instanceToTest() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(ClassToTest.self, configuration: { (definition : TyphoonDefinition!) -> Void in 
      definition.useInitializer("initWithObjectToStub:", parameters: { (initializer : TyphoonMethod!) -> Void in
        initializer.injectParameterWith(self.instancetoStubOut())
      })
    })
  }
}
```

My test class is solely for testing the instance of type `ClassToTest`, and I want to test it with the initializer-injected dependency on the object of type `SomeRealWorldClass` to be stubbed out. So I subclass RealAssembly so that `instanceToStubOut()` is overridden to return my stub object.

```
class MyTestClass : XCTestCase {
  var assembly : TestAssembly!

  class TestAssembly : RealAssembly {
    override dynamic func instanceToStubOut() -> AnyObject {
      return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(TestClass.self)
    }
  }

  @objc
  class TestClass : NSObject, ClassToStubOut {
    func methodToStubOut() { /* do nothing */ }
  }

  override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    self.assembly = TestAssembly().activate()
  }

  override func tearDown() {
    self.assembly = nil
    super.tearDown()
  }

  func testStuff() {
    let testingInstance = self.assembly.instanceToTest()
    XCTAssertTrue(testingInstance.doStuff(), "doStuff returns true")
  }
}
```

I expected this to work, but it doesn't. Typhoon seems to inject an uninitialized object instead of ever calling TestAssembly.instanceToStubOut()

Am I doing something wrong? Should I take a different approach?

EDIT: Here is some code you can paste into a Swift Playground that demonstrates the problem. The last line shows `c.otherInstance` returning `nil` :

```
import Typhoon

@objc
class BaseClass : NSObject {
    var otherInstance : OtherProtocol!

    func doIt() -> String {
        return self.otherInstance.doStuff()
    }
}

@objc
protocol OtherProtocol {
    func doStuff() -> String
}

@objc
class OtherImpl : NSObject, OtherProtocol {
    func doStuff() -> String {
        return "OtherClass"
    }
}

@objc
class StubClass : NSObject, OtherProtocol {
    func doStuff() -> String {
        return "Stubbed out"
    }
}

class BaseAssembly : TyphoonAssembly {
    dynamic func baseObject() -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(BaseClass.self,
            configuration: { (def : TyphoonDefinition!) -> Void in
            def.injectProperty("otherInstance", with: self.otherObject())
        })
    }

    dynamic func otherObject() -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(OtherImpl.self)
    }
}

var assembly = BaseAssembly()
assembly.activate()
var b = assembly.baseObject() as! BaseClass
b.doIt()

@objc
class TestAssembly : BaseAssembly {
    override func otherObject() -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(StubClass.self)
    }
}

var testAssembly = TestAssembly()
testAssembly.activate()
var c = testAssembly.baseObject() as! BaseClass
c.otherInstance // this shouldn't be nil
```

Comment: What you would like to do should be supported - will fix. Meanwhile, I believe there's a simple workaround - to verify could you please email the sample project to info@typhoonframework.org

Comment: Much appreciated @JasperBlues !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

While patching is an option, as outlined in @Herman's answer below, what was attempted in the question is a supported feature, however there was a regression bug preventing it from working correctly.

The regression bug has been fixed in Typhoon 3.2.2 and so now both patching and overriding an assembly are again options for configuring Typhoon for a particular use-case.

**Patching**

There is a patching feature for this purpose in Typhoon. Look [here](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Integration-Testing#patching-out-a-component).

For example:

```
class StubClass : NSObject, OtherProtocol {
    @objc func doStuff() -> String {
        return "Stubbed out"
    }
}

let assembly = BaseAssembly()
assembly.activate()
let b = assembly.baseObject() as! BaseClass
print(b.doIt())

let testAssembly = BaseAssembly().activate()
let patcher = TyphoonPatcher()
patcher.patchDefinitionWithSelector("otherObject") { () -> AnyObject! in
    return StubClass()
}

testAssembly.attachPostProcessor(patcher)
let c = testAssembly.baseObject() as! BaseClass
print(c.doIt())
```

Comment: Patching is an option, but also what was attempted should be supported. (Though it appears not working).

Comment: Thank you! I will use this until Jasper fixes the issue.

Comment: I wanted to confirm that this worked. Also, my original code works with current Typhoon HEAD on github. Thanks guys for the fast help and fix!